# Styling Bootstrap tabbable nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'd like the functionality of the Bootstrap tabbable nav but I want to style each tab with a background image and text underneath. In fact, what I'd really like is to just put my photoshop images right in each tab and set the active state to my selected image.

I'm having a very difficult time doing this. Is it going to take a lot of custom work to get this working with this component?

I thought I could just try with some CSS but it's not giving me the correct formatting I want:

```css
ul.nav.nav-tabs li {
    display:inline-block;
    background:url(../images/skypeIcon.png) no-repeat left center;
    background-size:20px auto;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:2px 0 2px 28px
}
```

By the way, I'm using Bootstrap 2.3 so I can't use Bootstrap 3 Navbar Generator.

Answer (score 0):

I can use a div tag inside my a tag and put whatever content I want in there.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

            <li class="active">

                <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">

                    <div>

                        <img src="<%=context%>/images/defaultAvatar.png"/>

                        <br/>

                        Computer

                    </div>

                </a>

            </li></ul>
```